# Same query over same database returning different result in different timezone

Tags: sql, postgresql

My team running the same query on the same database in 2 different timezones. The query is returning different result.
One of the reasons I think is I am converting my timestamp column to date using :

to_char(a.event_timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd'::text) AS "date"

Will this conversion depend on there local date time of the system?
I am testing for previous data range in the database.

Comment: Is `event_timestamp` a timestamp field and if so what type? Also if so why use `to_char`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver The data type is timestampz

Comment: What is the text of the query? If you don't want to show it all is the `to_char` conversion being used in the `WHERE or AND` clauses. If so don't, just use `a.event_timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has two different timestamp types: timestamp with time zone (`timestamptz`) and timestamp without time zone (`timestamp`). Note that in both of these types, Postgres internally stores a UTC timestamp without any time zone information. The difference is that a timestamp with time zone will be returned with / converted to the time zone information set for the user in that session on that machine.

If you've got a timestamp with time zone field, different users can get different results in timestamp-related queries depending on their local time zone settings. The best way to deal with this is to convert it in the query to a timestamp without a time zone by explicitly telling Postgres what timezone to convert it to. For example:

```
to_char( (a.event_timestamp at time zone 'Z'), 'yyyy-mm-dd'::text) AS "date"
```

will convert the timestamp with time zone to a timestamp without time zone that corresponds to that same time in UTC.